# how to join list of ints with ints output python

Tags: python, list

i have list of integers, how this list join to get output with the same list but joined every three value.

```
lst = [22, 33, 44, 11,33,11]
```

how to get

```
lstOutput = [223344, 113311]
```

with string everything clear, i try:

```
[lst[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(b), lst)]
```

Sorry for english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `map(str,lst[i:i+3])` to convert your int element to string then join them with `join` function  :

```
>>> [''.join(map(str,lst[i:i+3])) for i in range(0,len(lst),3)]
['223344', '113311']
```

and if you want the `int` value use this :

```
>>> l=[lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(lst),3)]
>>> [sum(j*(100**i) for i,j in enumerate(i[::-1])) for i in l]
[223344, 113311]
```

as `l` is equal `[[22, 33, 44], [11, 33, 11]]` and you need to multiple the element with 100 to power of index you need to reverse the split list by `[::-1]` and convert every list to its reverse like `[44, 33, 22]` and then add them.